# In KDB Q, how can I select the last letter of a symbol?

Tags: kdb

Say I have a table with an enumerated symbol column with values:

```
sym
_ _ _ _ 
AAPL
MSFT
INTC
```

I'm trying to select just the rows where the last letter of the symbol is `C`.

I've selecting against `last string sym` and `-1#string sym`, but I get an incompatible list length error every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `like` works for symbols as well as strings so no need to cast to string if you're trying to pattern match

```
q)select from ([]sym:`AAPL`MSFT`INTC`ABC) where sym like"*C"
sym
----
INTC
ABC
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
q)t: ([] sym: `AAPL`MSFT`INTC)
q)t
sym 
----
AAPL
MSFT
INTC
q)select last each string sym from t
sym
---
L  
T  
C
```